# Painting in "layers" with paintComponent() and inheritance

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, paintcomponent

I am attempting to create two components that each have a `paintComponent()` method -- The goal being that the parent object will paint default art, and the child object can then paint over it. An example could be creating playing cards: you have a parent `Card` class which paints a default card, then suite-specific classes which extend `Card` and paint their details on top of it.

Here is a diagram of what I am trying to accomplish:
[image]

Here is the code I am working with. My specific problem is: when the component is drawn -- if the child class does not have a `paintComponent` method -- the parents art is drawn. However, if I implement a `paintComponent` method on the child, the parents is not drawn, only the childs.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

abstract public class Tile extends JPanel {

    public static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 100;
    public static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 100;

    @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        //Set Size
        setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH,DEFAULT_HEIGHT);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        //Draw default art


    }
    @Override public Dimension getMinimumSize()
    { return new Dimension(DEFAULT_WIDTH,DEFAULT_HEIGHT); }

    @Override public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    { return getMinimumSize(); }

    //.....

}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CharacterTile extends Tile {

    protected char symbol;

    public CharacterTile(char symbol){
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }
    @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponents(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        //Draw details
    }

    //.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good use of inheritance. You should have something like:

```
Card
{
    Art front;
    Art back;
    paintComponent()
    {
        back.paintComponent();
        front.paintComponent();
    }
}
```

You could even have a List layers; and paint all the layers you need.

Sub classing is for splitting your code into smaller problems. For reusing code you should use polymorphism + object composition.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not what I'm trying to accomplish. I have edited the question to be more specific.